# error TS2307: Cannot find module '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client'

Tags: typescript, gulp, microsoft-graph-api, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I am very new to Typescript so I'm very sorry if this is obvious. Several hours of googling didn't solve it for me.

I try to import the module @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client to my typescript, but it throws the following error:

```
(3,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client'.
```

This is my package.json

```
{
 "name": "teams-app-1",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "Generate a Microsoft Teams application.",
 "repository": {
  "type": "git",
  "url": "https://some.url.com/_git/teams_app"
 },
 "license": "UNLICENSED",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
  "start": "node dist/server.js",
  "build": "gulp build",
  "postinstall": "bower install"
 },
 "engines": {
  "node": "8.9.x"
 },
 "dependencies": {
  "body-parser": "1.17.2",
  "browser-request": "0.3.3",
  "express": "4.15.3",
  "express-session": "1.15.4",
  "gulp": "3.9.1",
  "gulp-inject": "4.2.0",
  "gulp-util": "3.0.8",
  "gulp-zip": "4.0.0",
  "morgan": "1.8.2",
  "msal": "0.1.1",
  "nodemon": "1.11.0",
  "path": "^0.12.7",
  "run-sequence": "1.2.2",
  "superagent": "^3.8.2",
  "ts-loader": "2.3.2",
  "typescript": "^2.6.2",
  "webpack": "2.7.0"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
  "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client": "^1.0.0",
  "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types": "^1.1.0",
  "@types/body-parser": "1.16.4",
  "@types/express": "4.0.36",
  "@types/express-session": "0.0.32",
  "@types/morgan": "1.7.32",
  "@types/superagent": "^3.5.6"
 }
}
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types", 
        "node_modules/@microsoft"
    ]
 },
 "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist/web/assets/bower"
 ]
}
```

It tried it also with removing the attribute typeRoots, but it does not work either.

This is the line I try to call

```
 import {Client as GraphClient} from "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client";
```

The modules that are stored in @types are loaded successfully but @microsoft cannot be found. One strange thing: VisualStudio Code gives the correct path to the index.d.ts as a tooltip on "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client".

Can anybody help? Am I required to migrate to the old typings?

Comment: I try to use it for this sample: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/dev/samples/typescript/sample.ts

Comment: Are you still getting this error ? I have used the latest version of typescript (3.3.3) and @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client (1.4.0) to compile and it works fine for me.

Comment: The error was fixed later. I don't have the problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
"typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types", 
    "node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types/microsoft-graph.d.ts"
 ]
```

I think problem is that they are not using `index.d.ts` and if you specify folder inside typeRoots, the compiler is looking for that file.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately this does not work. I tried the following after checking for the exact location of the wanted files: "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types", "node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/src/inde‌​x.d.ts", "node_modules/@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types/microsoft-graph.d.ts" ] This are my current calls for the modules: import {Client as GraphClient} from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client'; import * as MicrosoftGraph from "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types"